# Writing and debugging C code using Xamarin Studio

Tags: c, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu laptop (using apt-get) and it had the ability to make C/C++ projects and debug them. The Windows version is called Xamarin Studio and it comes with tools to make mobile apps, but it lacks the ability to write and debug C or C++ code. Is there a way to write C in Xamarin Studio, a different version of MonoDevelop that works with C or a better IDE (that isn't Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you compile MonoDevelop on Windows yourself, and while doing that, you also compile the [CBinding](https://github.com/mhutch/cbinding) add-in.